# Print the output of a shell command in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I would like to turn the outut of a shell command into a variable e.g. $result and then print it out on screen e.g. print $result

```
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }'
```

Comment: You should check out a proper module for this, such as [Filesys::Df](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filesys::Df).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use backticks, and careful with the quoting:

```
my $result = `df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print \$5 " " \$1 }'`;
print $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a learner myself but I found this http://perldoc.perl.org/Shell.html useful... "This package is included as a show case, illustrating a few Perl features. It shouldn't be used for production programs".